# How to calculate the range of change of a Local oscillator

Tags: rf, mixer, homework

I was solving exercises from a book to prepare for exam and I found a question like this:
Determine the range of change the LO frequency and I have frequency of IF and RF ranging from 890-960 so what I did is calculating f(lo1)=890-f(IF) and f(lo2)=960+f(IF) and then from the results It ranges from  820 to 1030

second question was: Determine the value of frequencies before IF filter
so I calculated 
f(lo1)=820
f(lo2)=1030
f(lo3)=960
f(lo4)=890

is what I'm doing correct or false?

Comment: If your RF signal varies by 70MHz, then your LO needs to be able to sweep over a 70MHz range, it's as simple as that. It doesn't matter if you're running at 20-90MHz, 890-960MHz or 12.965GHz - 13.035GHz, your LO still needs to be able to sweep over the 70MHz range (sweep range = highest RF freq - lowest RF freq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the range limits for the LO, you must either add the IF to the both ends of the receiving range or subtract the IF from the both ends of the receiving range. The construction of the receiver states, is it add or subtract, but definitely not the both.

Before the IF filter there are available (assumed to have an ideal mixer + sinewave LO) all frequencies that are in radio's input filter's passband and have a signal, but shifted. Two instances occur for each frequency - one shifted downwards and one shifted upwards. The up and down shifts are equal to freq(LO). If the downshifts result negative results, forget the minus signs.